# How to correctly interpret ggplot's stat_density2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

My initial goal was to plot a population of individual points and then draw a convex hull enclosing 80% of that population centered on the mass of the population.

After trying a number of ideas, the best solution I came up with was to use `ggplot`'s `stat_density2d`.  While this works great for a qualitative analysis, I still need to indicate an 80% boundary.  I started out looking for a way to outline the 80th percentile **population** boundary, but I can work with an 80% **probability** density boundary instead.

Here's where I'm looking for help.  The `bin` parameter for `kde2d` (used by `stat_density2d`) is not clearly documented.  If I set `bin` = 4 in the example below, am I correct in interpreting the central (green) region as containing a 25% probability mass and the combined yellow, red, and green areas as representing a 75% probability mass?  If so, by changing the bin to = 5, would the area inscribed then equal an 80% probability mass?

```
set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))

TestData <- ggplot (data = df) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = as.factor(..level..)), 
  bins=4, geom = "polygon", ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "black"))

TestData
```

[image]

I repeated a number of test cases and manually counted the excluded points [would love to find a way to count them based on what ..level.. they were contained within] but given the random nature of the data (both my real data and the test data) the number of points outside of the `stat_density2d` area varied enough to warrant asking for help.

Summarizing, is there a practical means of drawing a polygon around the central 80% of the population of points in the data frame?  Or, baring that, am I safe to use `stat_density2d` and set bin equal to 5 to produce an 80% probability mass?

---

Excellent answer from Bryan Hanson dispelling the fuzzy notion that I could pass an undocumented `bin` parameter in `stat_density2d`.  The results looked close at values for `bin` around 4 to 6, but as he stated, the actual function is unknown and therefore not usable.

I used the HDRegionplot as provided in the accepted answer by DWin to solve my problem.  To that, I added a center of gravity (`COGravity`) and point in polygon (`pnt.in.poly`) from the `SDMTools` package to complete the analysis.

```
library(MASS)
library(coda)
library(SDMTools)
library(emdbook)
library(ggplot2)


theme_set(theme_bw(16))
set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))

HPDregionplot(mcmc(data.matrix(df)), prob=0.8)
with(df, points(x,y))
ContourLines <- as.data.frame(HPDregionplot(mcmc(data.matrix(df)), prob=0.8))
df$inpoly <- pnt.in.poly(df, ContourLines[, c("x", "y")])$pip

dp <- df[df$inpoly == 1,]
COG100 <- as.data.frame(t(COGravity(df$x, df$y)))
COG80 <- as.data.frame(t(COGravity(dp$x, dp$y)))

TestData <- ggplot (data = df) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = as.factor(..level..)), 
  bins=5, geom = "polygon", ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = as.factor(inpoly)), alpha = 1) +
  geom_point(data=COG100, aes(COGx, COGy),colour="white",size=2, shape = 4) +
  geom_point(data=COG80, aes(COGx, COGy),colour="green",size=4, shape = 3) +
  geom_polygon(data = ContourLines, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "blue", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "brown", "black", "white", "black", "white","black")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
TestData 
nrow(dp)/nrow(df) # actual number of population members inscribed within the 80% probability polgyon
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HPDregionplot in package:emdbook is supposed to do that. It does use MASS::kde2d but it normalizes the result. It has the disadvantage to my mind that it requires an mcmc object.

```
library(MASS)
library(coda)
HPDregionplot(mcmc(data.matrix(df)), prob=0.8)
with(df, points(x,y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alright, let me start by saying I'm not entirely sure of this answer, and it's only a partial answer!  There is no `bin` parameter for `MASS::kde2d` which is the function used by `stat_density2d`.  Looking at the help page for `kde2d` and the code for it (seen simply by typing the function name in the console), I think the `bin` parameter is `h` (how these functions know to pass `bin` to `h` is not clear however).  Following the help page, we see that if `h` is not provided, it is computed by `MASS:bandwidth.nrd`.  The help page for that function says this:

```
# The function is currently defined as
function(x)
{
    r <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75))
    h <- (r[2] - r[1])/1.34
    4 * 1.06 * min(sqrt(var(x)), h) * length(x)^(-1/5)
}
```

Based on this, I think the answer to your last question ("Am I safe...") is definitely no.  `r` in the above function is what you need for your assumption to be safe, but it is clearly modified, so you are not safe.  HTH.

Additional thought: Do you have any evidence that your code is using your `bins` argument?  I'm wondering if it is being ignored.  If so, try passing `h` in place of `bins` and see if it listens.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer by 42, I've simplified `HPDregionplot()` to reduce dependencies and remove the requirement to work with `mcmc`-objects. The function works on a two-column `data.frame` and creates no intermediate plots. Note, however, that the this approach breaks as soon as `grDevices::contourLines()` return multiple contours.

```r
hpd_contour <- function (x, n = 50, prob = 0.95, ...) {
  post1 <- MASS::kde2d(x[[1]], x[[2]], n = n, ...)

  dx <- diff(post1$x[1:2])
  dy <- diff(post1$y[1:2])
  sz <- sort(post1$z)
  c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy

  levels <- sapply(prob, function(x) {
    approx(c1, sz, xout = 1 - x)$y
  })

  as.data.frame(grDevices::contourLines(post1$x, post1$y, post1$z, levels = levels))
}
```

```r
theme_set(theme_bw(16))
set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))
ContourLines <- hpd_contour(df, prob=0.8)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = as.factor(..level..)), bins=5, geom = "polygon") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_polygon(data = ContourLines, color = "blue", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "brown", "black", "white", "black", "white","black")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

[image]

Moreover, the workflow now easily extends to grouped data.

```r
ContourLines <- iris[, c("Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")] %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(hpd_contour(.[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")], prob=0.8))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_polygon(data = ContourLines, fill = NA) +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin())
```

[image]

Comment: The bins argument seems to be fixed now. If you want to compute bins for each group, you need to compute them on normalised densities, see Claus WIlke's reply in this GitHub thread https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4113