# Why is bins parameter unknown for the stat_density2d function? (ggmap)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, ggproto

I have been stuck with this for hours. When I run this :

```
library(ggmap)
set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))

TestData <- ggplot (data = df) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = x, y = y,fill = as.factor(..level..)),bins=4, geom = "polygon",) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "black"))
```

I get this error message :

```
Error: Unknown parameters: bins
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why do you think there is a `bins` argument inside `stat_density2d`? It is not described in the help page.

Comment: It is not such a bad question. The OP should have posted this link though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329318/how-to-correctly-interpret-ggplots-stat-density2d since the code was copied from there.

Comment: Clearly the `bins` parameter has been removed, you can use the `n` parameter instead to change the contouring a bit, but I haven't seen how to directly control the number of levels generated. There probably is a way, but I need to research it more.

Comment: Someone who knows more about this function will undoubtedly enlighten us soon. Read the last post in the above link for the most information.

Comment: I don't think `stat_density2d` ever had a `bins` parameter. I checked version 0.8.6 (from 2010) and it was not there then. Version 2.0.0 is just more strict regarding accepting unexpected parameters.

Comment: It did not have a documented parameter per-se. But it had a parameter that was passed through to MASS:kde2d. Read the link I posted in the 2nd comment above for more information (and an example).

And in a similar way you can still use the parameters `n` or `h` which is not documented. Try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, adding this one as a second answer because I think the descriptions and comments in the first answer are useful and I don't feel like merging them. Basically I figured there must be an easy way to restore the regressed functionality. And after awhile, and learning some basics about `ggplot2`, I got this to work by overriding some `ggplot2` functions:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# -------------------------------
# start copy from stat-density-2d.R

stat_density_2d <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "density_2d",
                            position = "identity", contour = TRUE,
                            n = 100, h = NULL, na.rm = FALSE,bins=0,
                            show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatDensity2d,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      contour = contour,
      n = n,
      bins=bins,
      ...
    )
  )
}

stat_density2d <- stat_density_2d

StatDensity2d <- 
  ggproto("StatDensity2d", Stat,
          default_aes = aes(colour = "#3366FF", size = 0.5),

          required_aes = c("x", "y"),

          compute_group = function(data, scales, na.rm = FALSE, h = NULL,
                                   contour = TRUE, n = 100,bins=0) {
            if (is.null(h)) {
              h <- c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(data$x), MASS::bandwidth.nrd(data$y))
            }

            dens <- MASS::kde2d(
              data$x, data$y, h = h, n = n,
              lims = c(scales$x$dimension(), scales$y$dimension())
            )
            df <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = dens$x, y = dens$y), z = as.vector(dens$z))
            df$group <- data$group[1]

            if (contour) {
              #  StatContour$compute_panel(df, scales,bins=bins,...) # bad dots...
              if (bins>0){
                StatContour$compute_panel(df, scales,bins)
              } else {
                StatContour$compute_panel(df, scales)
              }
            } else {
              names(df) <- c("x", "y", "density", "group")
              df$level <- 1
              df$piece <- 1
              df
            }
          }
  )

# end copy from stat-density-2d.R
# -------------------------------

set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))

TestData <- ggplot (data = df) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = x, y = y,fill = as.factor(..level..)),bins=5,geom = "polygon") +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "black"))
print(TestData)
```

Which yields the result. Note that varying the `bins` parameter has the desired effect now, which cannot be replicated by varying the `n` parameter.

[image]

Comment: I just got a notice that this has been fixed in the github version of ggplot2, and the bug was closed by hadley.

Answer (score 0):

### update:

After an extended discussion with Roland (see the comments), he determined it is probably a regression bug and filed a bug report.

---

As the question is "why is the `bins` parameter unknown?", and I spent a fair amount of time researching it, I will answer it.

Your example obviously comes from this link from Oct 2013, where the parameter is used. [How to correctly interpret ggplot's stat_density2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329318/how-to-correctly-interpret-ggplots-stat-density2d)

However it was never a documented parameter, and it is not clear that it is being used there. It is probably a parameter that is being passed through to other libraries (like MASS) that are being used by `stat_density2d`.

We can get the code to work by getting rid of the `scale_fill_manual` call and using this:

```
library(ggmap)
set.seed(1)
n=100

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n, 0, 1), y=rnorm(n, 0, 1))

TestData <- ggplot (data = df) +
  stat_density2d(aes(x = x, y = y,fill = as.factor(..level..)), geom = "polygon",) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) 
#  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","red","green","royalblue", "black"))
print(TestData)
```

which yields this:
[image]

Since this looks rather different from the plot posted in the original Oct 2013 link, I would say that `stat_density2d` has been extensively rewritten since then, or maybe `MASS:kde2d` (or another MASS routine), and that the `bin` parameter is no longer accepted. It is also not clear that that parameter ever did anything (read the link).

You can however vary the parameters `n` and `h` - also undocumented from the `stat_density2d` point-of-view (as far as I can tell).

Comment: `MASS::kde2d` doesn't have a `bins` parameter.

Comment: Maybe it used to. Clearly something else did. Did you read the post this originated from? They go over it in some detail there.

Comment: I don't think so. See the second answer there.

Comment: The post from Bryan Hanson? He talks about `bins`. He doesn't understand what it does, or how it is used, but it clearly was a parameter that the function accepted. What is your point?

Comment: Also take a careful look at the first two plots. The first one has `bins=4` and has 4 colored buckets of values. The second one has `bins=5`, and has 5 colored buckets. So that is what `bins` did apparently. And that functionality is now gone... And the OP here got hung up on that, because that is what he wanted to control.

Comment: I checked. `kde2d` didn't have a `bins` parameter even back in 2009. `stat_density2d` didn't have one then either. You could check further back (the old versions are archivated on CRAN), but I don't think it ever had any effect. The OP of the linked questions even confirms that.

Comment: Then it was some other function that `stat_density2d` used. How else do you explain the appearance of the original post from 2013? We could chat about it if you want. I live in Germany so we are probably in the same timezone.

Comment: OK, I had a closer look. The `bins` parameter was actually passed to `stat_contour`. Since the ellipses from `stat_density` are no longer passed to `stat_contour`, it is no longer possible to specify the number of bins. This seems like a regression. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, I just found this. It is a very useful feature. https://github.com/trinker/embodied/blob/master/inst/example_plots/Density.md

Comment: I think hans glick deserves an upvote for his suffering. I gave him one, but it only got him to 0.

Comment: Sorry, but he won't get one from me unless he adds his `sessionInfo()` to the question.